# Why does my java app not work on another computer?

Tags: java

I programmed a game on Netbeans(using java), and after I was done I clicked "clean and build" (which makes it to a compiled java app). I tested it on my computer first and it worked perfectly, but when I tried running it on other computers its said that it can't find a class file that has the main method. 
Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it? Plz someone help.

Comment: How did you try running it on other computers?

Comment: If you are making jar, make sure META-INF has entry of your main method class.

Comment: - Is Java installed in the other computer?
- Did you use some library?

Comment: Post your exact error message, google it, realize it's a classpath error, fix.

Comment: Nishtant shreshth - it was made in compiled in a .jar and I just click on it

Comment: Nambari- it is in a jar and how do I entry meta inf

Comment: @MarkBtesh: One way is, goto file view and edit manifest.mf and add entry Main-Class: yourclasswith full package

Comment: Go to `Properies (of your project)->run->Main Class`, set class that should be run by default, "clean and build" again and try to use jar created inside dist folder of your application.

Comment: Pshemo - it works on my computer but not others.. Are you sure that would help?

Comment: I am sure it is worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Netbeans, right click on your project and click Configuration. Click on "More Options" and in the middle there is a line that says "Main class" change that then retry your clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

While running the application specify the class with main method on the command line:

```
java -cp jarfile.jar org.comp.MainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the clean build, check output logs of the build process. It should state something like this:

> To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
>
> java -jar Example.jar

Use that specified command and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have the same Java Version ?

is there a lib folder ? If so that is also needed

Can you post the jar ?